# Is a smooth curve (in the projective plane) always irreductible?

Tags: algebraic-curves, projective-space

Is a smooth curve (in the projective plane) always irreductible?
If so, does it hold for higher dimensions, too?
Is there an elementary argument?

I believe that I managed to show it for cubic curves, but I needed a case analysis (depending on how a cubic may factorize), which seems to me unsuitable for coping with an arbitrary degree or dimension.

Comment: If $C=C_1 \cup C_2$, then Bezout tells you there is an intersection point, and the curve is not smooth there

Comment: This answers my question, indeed. Thanks.